# Does Win 2012 Standard Edition support clustering of SQL 2012 Enterprise Edition?

Tags: windows-server-2012, cluster, sql-server-2012

Can you cluster SQL 2012 Enterprise Edition on Win 2012 Standard Edition?  The features doesn't seem to clarify whether it allowed or not.

We are seeing warning “Cluster Nodes Failed" in the SQL installation log, and SQL does not come up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it does.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/08/20/step-by-step-creating-a-sql-server-2012-alwayson-availability-group.aspx

All editions of Server 2012 allow clustering.

Comment: Yes. SQL 2012 Always On Failover Clustering and Always On Availability Groups both rely on Windows Server Failover Clustering which, as mentioned, is available in all editions of Server 2012.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx